# Asp.net core 2 webapi post related data insert

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I tell EF Core to not insert related data on post ?

this are my models for Deposito and Sucursal

```
public class IDeposito
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descrip { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public Boolean Activo { get; set; }
        public ISucursal Sucursal { get; set; }
    }
public class ISucursal
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descrip { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public Boolean Activo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] IDeposito postData)
    {
        if (postData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _context.Depositos.Add(postData);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetDeposito", new { ID = postData.Id }, postData);
    }
```

When I post this model
   {
        "Descrip": "Neuquen",
        "Alias": "NQN",
        "Activo": true,
        "Sucursal": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Descrip": "Comodoro Rivadavia",
            "Alias": "CR",
            "Activo": true
        }
    }

It fails because it tries to insert into table "Sucursal", although there already exists a "Sucursal" with id: 1.

Is there anyway I can tell EF Core to not update the related tables ? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach if you want connect new IDeposito  to existing ISucursal with Id = 1 then use:

```
postData.Sucursal =  _context.Sucursals.Find(postData.Sucursal.Id);
_context.Depositos.Add(postData);
_context.SaveChanges();

return CreatedAtRoute("GetDeposito", new { ID = postData.Id }, postData);
```

If you want add only IDeposito  without any sucursal:

```
postData.Sucursal = null;
_context.Depositos.Add(postData);
_context.SaveChanges();

return CreatedAtRoute("GetDeposito", new { ID = postData.Id }, postData);
```

Comment: Wow !!! this line made it : postData.Sucursal =  _context.Sucursales.Find(postData.Sucursal.Id);    Don't really understand why, but with that line of code, EF doesn't try to insert a new Sucursal. Thank you very much, now I can clean up all my controllers.

Comment: Because entity from postData is not tracked by EF Core. When you get entity from Db entity framework add this entity to tracking and know that it shouldn't add it as new but just connect new IDeposito  with existing Secursal

Comment: Now it makes much more sense,  maybe I should read more about how EF tracks data. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Also something to note when you're making your models is to include the [Table] attribute on top of the class name